# Installing fastlane plugin in jenkins via pipeline script

Tags: ruby, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fastlane

I am trying to run a build in jenkins. In the course of execution of build, Jenkins clones the git in the workspace. After checking if the fastlane folder is there or not, it creates the folder containing `fastfile`, `matchfile`, `appfile`, `pluginfile`. After that I am trying to install the diwai plugin via `fastlane install_plugins` in the workspace. But when it reaches the install_plugins step, it shows this

> ```
> Installing plugin dependencies...
> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
> /users/<username>/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.5/.document
> An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.5), and Bundler cannot
> continue.
> Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.
> ```

Since my jenkins user does not have the admin/ sudo privileges I used a workaround, I added users/< username >/.gem to my environment variable path in jenkins,

The question is how can I resolve this error, I can't provide my jenkin's user the admin privileges. I also tried to `chmod 777 users/<username>/.fastlane/bin` to make it readable/writable/executable

Point me in correct direction, if my understanding of error is correct or I would need a  new approach. If any other information is required please let me know

Thanks for your help